# Build error with map_view, flutter & gradle

Tags: android, kotlin, flutter, sdk, dependencies

I get a build error using flutter version 1.2.2 and map_view version 0.0.14.

I tried to use this code in build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.2-4'
```

I followed all the steps here https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/map_view#-readme-tab-

I have an api-key but get the following build error

```
 Error running Gradle: ProcessException: Process “C:UsersAlmoit PCDesktopMyAppMapflutter_app2androidgradlew.bat” exited
abnormally:

Configure project :map_view
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (27.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove “buildToolsVersion ‘27.0.3’” from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.2.51 and higher. Project ‘android’ is using
version 1.1.2-4.

Try: Run with –stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with –info or –debug option to get more log output. Run with –scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s Command: C:UsersAlmoit
PCDesktopMyAppMapflutter_app2androidgradlew.bat app:properties
```

With flutter doctor, everything seems fine.

```
flutter doctor -v

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.437], locale en-AI)
    • Flutter version 1.2.1 at C:flutter
    • Framework revision 8661d8aecd (10 weeks ago), 2019-02-14 19:19:53 -0800
    • Engine revision 3757390fa4
    • Dart version 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:Program FilesAndroidAndroid Studiojrebinjava
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at C:Program FilesAndroidAndroid Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 33.4.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • SPH L520 • 2d81b4cf • android-arm • Android 4.4.2 (API 19)

• No issues found!
```

I searched it everywhere but can't find the answer. Please help me regarding this.

Comment: If anyone could solve this error, please help me out..

Answer (score 0):

In your /android/build.gradle try increasing the version of the kotlin gradle plugin like so:

```
classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.0'
```

I read somewhere that flutter now only support version 1.3+.
I just tried it and now I can at least build my app for android.

PS: Since you are using an older version of flutter maybe the kotlin plugin will work with an older version as mentioned in the error messages:

```
classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.51'
```